# Angular HttpClientModule not making http request on page load

Tags: angular, http

I have an issue with newly upgraded Angular 10 that I cannot figure out. I say Angular 10 because this was working in Angular 9. Although from the changelogs, etc. I can't figure out why the app is acting this way.
I basically have a login page, which on login takes you to the main Dashboard view of the app. When user logs in, it is suppose to be make a http request to get certain dashboard widgets data, etc. But it does not. What's puzzling is that if I refresh the dashboard page, it does make the http request at that point. It's only coming in from the login page to dashboard page when it does not make the http request. So I am not sure if I am not loading in the dependencies correctly or in correct order or what...

This is my signin.component.ts - which is what navigates to the dashboard view on successful login

```
this.authStatusSub = this.authService.getAuthStatusListener()
    .subscribe(authObject=>{
        if(!authObject) {
            if(authObject.authenticated === false) {
                this.toastr.error('User cannot be authenticated', 'Login failed');
                this.loading = false;
                return;
            }       
        } else if (authObject.authenticated === true) {
            this.store.setItem("login_status", true);
            
            if(authObject.redirectUrl) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl(authObject.redirectUrl);
            } else {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard/v1'); 
            }
            
        }    
        this.loading = false;
            
    })
```

This is the dashboard.component.ts that loads after login. I know this component is instantiated because of the console.log there :) I stripped down everything irrelevant btw. I know the code would have errors below.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardService } from 'src/app/shared/services/dashboard.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { InventoryService } from 'src/app/shared/services/inventory.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-dashboad-default',
templateUrl: './dashboad-default.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dashboad-default.component.css']
})
export class DashboadDefaultComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
    private dashboardService: DashboardService
    , private toastr: ToastrService
    , private inventoryService: InventoryService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    console.log('here')
    this.dashboardService.onDashboardMain();
    this.dashboardSub = 
    this.dashboardService.getDashboardMain()
    .subscribe((res:any)=>{
        
       console.log('here 1');
        this.isLoading = false;
    }, (err)=> {
        this.toastr.error('Error occurred in snapshot load', 'Error ocurred!');
        this.isLoading = false;
    });

}

}
```

It never makes the http request so it never goes inside of the .subscribe() nor the error handler.

Here is my dashboard.service.ts file that makes the http request.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { LocalStoreService } from "./local-store.service";

const BACKEND_URL = environment.ApiBaseUrl +'/dashboard';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DashboardService { 
private dashboardMainSnapshot = new Subject<any>();

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private localService: LocalStoreService) {}

getDashboardMain() {
    return this.dashboardMainSnapshot.asObservable();
}


onDashboardMain() {
    let userName = this.localService.getItem('username');
    const body = {
        username: userName
    }
    this.http.post(BACKEND_URL+'/getDashboardMain', body)
    .subscribe((res:any)=>{
        this.dashboardMainSnapshot.next({status:true, dashboardSnapshot: res.content});
    }, (err)=>{
        this.dashboardMainSnapshot.next({status:false});
    })
}
}
```

Here is my app.module.ts file.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './shared/services/auth-interceptor';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';


import { LaddaModule } from 'angular2-ladda';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
SharedModule,
HttpClientModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
ToastrModule.forRoot({
  timeOut: 10000,
  positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
  preventDuplicates: true,
  progressBar: true
}),
AppRoutingModule,
LaddaModule
],
providers: [
DatePipe,
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true
}
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { SearchModule } from './components/search/search.module';
import { SharedComponentsModule } from './components/shared-components.module';
import { SharedDirectivesModule } from './directives/shared-directives.module';
import { SharedPipesModule } from './pipes/shared-pipes.module';

@NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule,
PerfectScrollbarModule,
SearchModule,
NgbModule,
SharedComponentsModule,
SharedDirectivesModule,
SharedPipesModule,
RouterModule
]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Finally, this is the app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from './shared/components/layouts/auth-layout/auth-layout.component';
import { AuthGaurd } from './shared/services/auth.gaurd';
import { AdminLayoutSidebarLargeComponent } from './shared/components/layouts/admin-layout-sidebar- 
large/admin-layout-sidebar-large.component';

const adminRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'dashboard',
  loadChildren: () => import('./views/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
},
{
  path: 'pages',
  loadChildren: () => import('./views/pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule)
}
];

const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: AuthLayoutComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'sessions',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/sessions/sessions.module').then(m => m.SessionsModule)
  }
]
},
{
path: '',
component: AdminLayoutSidebarLargeComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGaurd],
children: adminRoutes
},
{
path: '**',
redirectTo: 'others/404'
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true , onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', 
preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [AuthGaurd]//added 
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any other component or anything. I've tried everything I could think of.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Edit***
To simply everything. In dashboard.component.ts went back to the basics

```
this.dashboardSnapshotSub = this.dashboardService.onDashboardMain()
    .subscribe((res:any)=>{
        console.log(res);
    })
```

Dashboard.service.ts

```
onDashboardMain() {
    console.log('here');
    return this.http.get(BACKEND_URL+'/getDashboardMain')
}
```

This produces this error, which is what I got initially before starting to debug this issue.

ERROR TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

Comment: I know that. I tried stripping down everything to make the question short as possible :)

Comment: Possibly the `dashboardMainSnapshot` obsevable is emitted before the subscription. Try replacing the `Subject` with `private dashboardMainSnapshot = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);`.

Comment: Well that did emit the subscription so it did get into the .subscribe(). Although it still didn't call the this.dashboardService.onDashboardMain(); to make the http request.

Comment: Without the subscription in the `onDashboardMain()` function, how do you expect the `getDashboardMain()` observable to emit?

Comment: Can you look at my edit. It's very basic code so I am not sure of that error, which again is what i received initially. Now I'm thinking the issue is something else? Again, the site works if I refresh the page on dashboard view.

Comment: To answer your previous question, onDashboardMain() would have emitted with .next(), and I am subscribing to that observable in dashboard.component which is being returned as observable with getDashboardMaint(). Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I basically did more digging around and found the issue with my Http-interceptor even though I haven't exactly found a fix for it. But if I remove the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS object from the providers array in app.module.ts, it works. It does make the http request. 
So now to determine what's causing that issue. Thanks